# Google Play Billing Library not giving orderId when purchase transaction is failed or cancelled but it's coming in console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library

I have integrated Play Billing Library to my android app.
I need to get the orderId even if some transaction gets failed or user cancels it.

```
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int resultCode, List<Purchase> purchases)
```

Above method only returns resultCode with purchases as null value in failure/cancel case.

But in play console, I am able to see the purchase orderId , time etc.: `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=xxxxxx#OrderManagementPlace`

Can someone help how can I get the orderID field?

Comment: Also does Google Play provide any API  through which I can fetch all the purchase transaction of all the users from my backend. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is seems a bug, and currently there is no solution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112749359